# Accessing the DOM of a loaded page from main process in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I know that the best way to access the HTML document is from the renderer process and I should be using a chain of ipcMain/ipcRenderer calls to do that from the main process. However, in this situation I have to do it all from the main, so I am doing it with `.executeJavascript()`

**The error I get**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Script failed to execute, this normally means an error was thrown. Check the renderer console for the error.
[1]     at WebFrame.e.startsWith.e.startsWith.WebFrame.<computed> [as _executeJavaScript] (electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:67:1601)
[1]     at electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:91:463
[1]     at electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:75:390
[1]     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:79:757)
[1]     at EventEmitter.emit (electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:146:3752)
[1]     at Object.onMessage (electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle.js:127:1253)
```

**What I have tried**

[1]

```
this.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      require('electron').ipcRenderer.send('acquired-page-dom', String(document.body.innerHTML));
    `);
      ipcMain.once('acquired-page-dom', (ev, html) => {
        console.log('~#~#~')
        console.log(3)
        e.sender.send('got-page-dom', html)
      })
```

It didn't work. So I tried in the second attempt to pass the document as a string, as I heard that the sent object has to be serialisable

[2]

```
this.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      var html = String(document.body.innerHTML);
      require('electron').ipcRenderer.send('acquired-page-dom', document.body.innerHTML);
    `)
      ipcMain.once('acquired-page-dom', (ev, html) => {
        console.log('~#~#~')
        console.log(3)
        e.sender.send('got-page-dom', html)
      })
```

It gave the same error.

**Conclusion**

It isn't really about the ipcRenderer bit within the `.executeJavascript` function. Even if I pass in a simple function like  `` .executeJavascript(`alert('hello')`); `` I still get the same error. The devTool doesn't add anything to that error message, so I don't really know how I can further debug this and I am stuck.

**The context where I get the error**

I am getting this error only when I have a webpage loaded in my viewer.
If I am on my homepage, which is fairly light, I do not get this error.

P.S.
NodeIntegration is also set to True:

```
this.browserView = new BrowserView({
      webPreferences: {
        preload: `${app.getAppPath()}/build/view-preload.bundle.js`,
        nodeIntegration: false,
        contextIsolation: true,
        sandbox: true,
        enableRemoteModule: false,
        partition: incognito ? 'view_incognito' : 'persist:view',
        plugins: true,
        nativeWindowOpen: true,
        webSecurity: true,
        javascript: true,
      },
    });
```